# Javascript url regex returns a comma at the end of the url, any way to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regex to match URLs.  It matches very well for anything that is written with `www.` or starts with `http://` but, it adds a comma to any matched urls. For example when I take the value from a textarea and match it up and then replace the textarea value with the matched value it places a comma at the end of the url:

```
var urlexp = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;

$('button').click(function(){

var text = $('.textarea').val();
if((text.match(urlexp))) {

var urlMatch = urlexp.exec(text);

$('.textarea').val(urlMatch);
}
});
```

When I type ***http://www.google.com*** and click the button ***http://www.google.com*** is replaced with ***http://www.google.com,*** which is causing a problem, is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem isn't with the regex, it's with you setting the val.

try:

```
$('.textarea').val(urlMatch[0]);
```

Comment: Errortype "regular expression of 'urlMatch' [null] is not defined

Comment: You should only get that if you're putting it on another line since you'll be executing the regex twice and there will be no 2nd match.  You should only have one like with `.exec()`.  Remove the `g` flag from the end of the regex if it keeps happening (the `g` in `/gi`)

Comment: actually i just noticed, if i add http:// it returns just fine, but if i leave out the http then the comma is added to the end. and what if i am using this more than once?

Answer (score 0):

How about using match:

```
var textarea = $('.textarea');
var text = textarea.val();
var match = text.match(urlexp);

if (match) {
    textarea.val(match[0]);
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me, just returns no result, if the url has http:// before it then it works fine, but if the http:// is missing a comma is added to the end of the string.